# Fix height of a table row in HTML Table

Tags: html

Kindly look at the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="content" height="525" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr style="height:9px"><td height="9" bgcolor="#990000">Upper</td></tr>
<tr><td  bgcolor="#990099">Lower</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

IE ignores the "height:9px" and I can't get what I want.
Also, without the DOCTYPE, it works. But I have to follow the standard so that DOCTYPE cannot be removed.
Does anyone how to fix the height of the upper row?

Some clarifications:
1. The height of second row may vary according to users' action and cannot be fixed.
2. The height of the table is set to 525px so the table has a minimum height of 525px

Comment: try now, stick buncha data in the second row ... set width:20px; to see the effect quick

Comment: just wondering if the upper row is actually a header, explicitly using thead and tbody with heights may be easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the bottom cell will grow as you enter more text ... setting the table width will help too

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="content" style="min-height:525px; height:525px; width:100%; border:0px; margin:0; padding:0; border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr><td style="height:10px; background-color:#900;">Upper</td></tr>
<tr><td style="min-height:515px; height:515px; background-color:#909;">lower<br/>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and stick all the other "view" properties into your style attribute, better yet - external css file :)

Comment: Some clarifications:
1. The height of second row may vary according to users' action and cannot be fixed.
2. The height of the table is set to 525px so the table has a minimum height of 525px

Comment: try it, bottom cell will grow with the content ... set width:50px; to see results quick

Answer (score 1):

This works, as long as you remove the height attribute from the table.

```
<table id="content" border="0px" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="0px">
  <tr><td height='9px' bgcolor="#990000">Upper</td></tr>
  <tr><td height='100px' bgcolor="#990099">Lower</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

my css

```
TR.gray-t {background:#949494;}
h3{
    padding-top:3px;
    font:bold 12px/2px Arial;
}
```

my html

```
<TR class='gray-t'>
<TD colspan='3'><h3>KAJANG</h3>
```

I decrease the 2nd size in font.

`padding-top` is used to fix the size in IE7.